# Debug registers (DRx) keep getting trampled when using with SetThreadContext

Tags: breakpoint

I'm trying to set hardware breakpoints from code by using Get/SetThreadContext and modifying DR0..3, DR7, but it only works if I do it repeatedly. Most of the time when I use Get after having used Set before, I see the values completely trampled (sometimes to 0s, sometimes to bogus numbers which are clearly not even addresses). Get's return value is always 1. Sometimes it sticks for a while and the breakpoint hits. What could cause is and is there a way to track it? I tried setting a code breakpoint in SetThreadContext in ntdll, but it's only being called from my code. It happens with and without VS attached. I must add it's a game engine project, so it might be that some 3rd party lib does that.
The config is Ryzen 3900, Windows 10 20H2, Windows SDK 10.0.14393, VS 2017

Answer (score 1):

ok turns out it was a rookie mistake - i didn't set ContextFlags to CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS before calling GetThreadContext

Comment: Thanks for adding the resolution!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like some anti-debugging measure and is probably done by a kernel driver so you won't catch it with user-mode breakpoints. Check the driver list before and after installing the game, that should show the culprit.

Comment: i mean it's my own project, i'm not attaching to something (i probably chose a wrong hub for the question, but when googling this one seemed to be the closest). since then i actually replicated it in a very stripped down application with no 3rd parties, and it still does exactly the same thing.